# NullPointerException 7

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I have 3 classes in the same package that are relevant to the problem: MainClass, Player and Ground. In Player.java, I need to access a variable that is declared in MainClass like so:

```
private static Ground ground;
...
ground= new Ground(440);
```

There's also a getter for ground that I want to use. This is Ground.java:

```
package cratejumper;

public class Ground {
    private int Y;

    public Ground(int height) {
        Y = height;
    }

    public int getY() {
        return Y;
    }

    public void setY(int y) {
        Y = y;
    }

}
```

Now I access ground from MainClass.java in Player.java like so:

```
private static Ground ground = MainClass.getGround();
```

But when I try to access ground.getY() in Player.java, it throws a nullpointerexception at runtime. I get no error when writing the code in eclipse. This is the part where I want to use ground in Player.java

```
39 if (Y + speedY >= ground.getY()-HEIGHT) {
40          Y = ground.getY()-HEIGHT;
41          speedY = 0; 
42          jumped=false;}
```

I can't find the error! I basically do the same thing with another class called Background.java without any problems.

Comment: Sounds like `MainClass.getGround()` is returning `null`.

Comment: `ground` is private how can you get the value?

Comment: @tintinmj With the getter, like he shows: `MainClass.getGround()`

Comment: Show us your `MainClass`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
private static Ground ground;
```

The above line is executed when the MainClass class is loaded  (presumably, at the very beginning of the application). After this line has been executed, ground is null.

```
private static Ground ground = MainClass.getGround();
```

The above line is executed when the Player class is loaded (presumably, at the very beginning of the application).

And finally

```
ground= new Ground(440);
```

is executed, but we can't know when, because we don't have your full code. But presumably, it's executed after the Player class has been loaded.

Non-constant static fields are usually a sign of poor design. Consider passing objects around, instead of using static fields.

Comment: +1 for the last sentence – the design should really have a `Player` object that takes `Ground` as a constructor parameter, in order to make the dependency explicit. IMO in OO code, `static` should mostly be used for constants and in API surfaces, not for internally structuring code.